# start notion in cmd without it being tied to the command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, notion

When i open notion in cmd using

```
start notion
```

it opens with the command line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srKeK.png)

How do i make it just open by itself without being tied to the command line?
Notion also closes whenever i close the cmd window.

For example, if i were to open Firefox or Outlook using the start command,
it will just open without any output from the command line.

Thanks for your help.

i have tried using

```
start /b notion
```

to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Notion is just an electron app. So it's possible to set nodejs and electron env variables to change behavior.

Snippet below when placed in batch .bat file will start notion app without logging anything to console and also will not block console such that when you close console window notion app will also close.
I assume that notion.exe is in the default installation path.

For example: `start_notion.bat` content:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE=true
start "" C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Notion\Notion.exe
endlocal
```

from documentation:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/environment-variables#electron_no_attach_console-windows
`ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE=true` means "Don't attach to the current console session."

Alternatively you can use oneliner if you want to paste directly to the console:

```
set ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE=true && start "" C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Notion\Notion.exe
```

Tested on version: `Notion 2.18.23.10.26.98`